# HTML How to change the destination page based on the radio button selected

Tags: html, css, html-table, radio-button

I have a table of student information with a radio button next to each student's name. At the bottom of the page I have a Submit button. How do I make it so when a student's radio button is selected and the Submit button is hit the specified student's information page comes up? I would like to do this solely in HTML (maybe using a form for each student?).

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Update Student Job Search Information</title>
</head>

<style>
    table {
        border: 4px solid black;
        border-spacing: 15px;
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <h2> Update Student Job Search Information </h2>
    <h3>Current Participants</h3>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select Student</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Project ID</th>
                <th>Avg. Eval. Score</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Maddie Hester</td>
                    <td>mhester</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>KOK</td>
                    <td>87</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Khloe Morley</td>
                    <td>kmorley</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>UP</td>
                    <td>95</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Bethany Bain</td>
                    <td>bbain</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>VID</td>
                    <td>74</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Ebony Wyatt</td>
                    <td>ewyatt</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>NICK</td>
                    <td>91</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Susannah Howells</td>
                    <td>showell</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>BEAR</td>
                    <td>32</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Chelsea Wilder</td>
                    <td>cwilder</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>BEAR</td>
                    <td>87</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Athena Wiggins</td>
                    <td>awiggin</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>NICK</td>
                    <td>89</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Ava Fritz</td>
                    <td>afritz</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>UP</td>
                    <td>91</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Ellena Kemp</td>
                    <td>ekemp</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>VID</td>
                    <td>92</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Sophia York</td>
                    <td>syork</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>KOK</td>
                    <td>98</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>India Kelley</td>
                    <td>ikelley</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>VID</td>
                    <td>95</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Zuzanna Rigby</td>
                    <td>zrigby</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>KOK</td>
                    <td>100</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Cindy Townsend</td>
                    <td>ctownse</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>BEAR</td>
                    <td>93</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Catrin Thorpe</td>
                    <td>cthorpe</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>UP</td>
                    <td>95</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Alyssa Bowes</td>
                    <td>abowes</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>KOK</td>
                    <td>95</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Miley Whitehead</td>
                    <td>mwhiteh</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>BEAR</td>
                    <td>98</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Bodhi Hulme</td>
                    <td>bhulme</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>VID</td>
                    <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Aaron Ware</td>
                    <td>aware</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>NICK</td>
                    <td>78</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Sydney Davison</td>
                    <td>sdaviso</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>UP</td>
                    <td>99</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Preston Tomlinson</td>
                    <td>ptomlin</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>NICK</td>
                    <td>45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Gerard Hagan</td>
                    <td>ghagan</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>KOK</td>
                    <td>96</td>
            </tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" </td>
                <td>Evan McCaffrey</td>
                <td>emccaff</td>
                <td>Active</td>
                <td>NICK</td>
                <td>97</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" </td>
                        <td>Darrell Stokes</td>
                        <td>dstokes</td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td>UP</td>
                        <td>988</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" </td>
                        <td>Naveah Carty</td>
                        <td>ncarty</td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td>BEAR</td>
                        <td>85</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" </td>
                        <td>Juan Robson</td>
                        <td>jrobson</td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td>VID</td>
                        <td>99</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" </td>
                        <td>Oliwier Flores</td>
                        <td>oflores</td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td>VID</td>
                        <td>100</td>
                </tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" </td>
                    <td>Owain Barker</td>
                    <td>obarker</td>
                    <td>Active</td>
                    <td>NICK</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" </td>
                            <td>Ned Gallegos</td>
                            <td>ngalleg</td>
                            <td>Active</td>
                            <td>BEAR</td>
                            <td>97</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" </td>
                            <td>Montel Zimmerman</td>
                            <td>mzimmer</td>
                            <td>Active</td>
                            <td>UP</td>
                            <td>96</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio" </td>
                            <td>Leland White</td>
                            <td>lwhite</td>
                            <td>Active</td>
                            <td>KOK</td>
                            <td>98</td>
                    </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Comment: If you want a different action according to what a user selected, you are going to need to use javascript

Comment: Why don't you just make each student's name a hyperlink to his/her page instead of using a form?

Comment: You will need some sort of server-side script (or JavaScript) in order to carry out a different action based on which used is selected. Alternatively, you could simply use hyperlinks (as suggested). While this **can** be achieved with raw HTML / CSS... it would be incredibly clunky and poor practise to go about it that way.

Comment: Why do you only want to use raw HTML / CSS?
Also, how many students will this form be for? Can you display that amount by just using radio buttons? If you're working with forms and data, does that mean you have a database you'll be sending the information to? Because if that's the case, you'll already be working with PHP right?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use only HTML+CSS but consider it as a kind of hack. It should be implemented by some JS code. 
Here is a shorter list, JavaScript is used only to show different behaviour based on student selection and can be changed to form submitting with some parameter:

```css
.students-list {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.students-list input+button {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.students-list input:checked+button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Update Student Job Search Information</title>
</head>

  <style>
    table {
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-spacing: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

  </style>

<body style="padding-bottom: 5em;">

 <h2> Update Student Job Search Information </h2>
  <h3>Current Participants</h3>
  <div class="students-list">
   <table>
   <thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Select Student</th>
  <th>Student Name</th>
  <th>Username</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>Project ID</th>
  <th>Avg. Eval. Score</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="student"/><button type="button" onClick="alert('Selected: Ned Gallegos')">Submit</button></td>
  <td>Ned Gallegos</td>
  <td>ngalleg</td>
  <td>Active</td>
  <td>BEAR</td>
  <td>97</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="student" /><button type="button" onClick="alert('Selected: Montel Zimmerman')">Submit</button></td>
  <td>Montel Zimmerman</td>
  <td>mzimmer</td>
  <td>Active</td>
  <td>UP</td>
  <td>96</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="student"/><button type="button" onClick="alert('Selected: Leland White')">Submit</button></td>
  <td>Leland White</td>
  <td>lwhite</td>
  <td>Active</td>
  <td>KOK</td>
  <td>98</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
<br>
</body>
```